# Query optimization by reusing the inner query only once

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

Consider the below Query

```
SELECT
  FlightDate,
  FlightNum,
  Origin,
  Dest,
  AirlineID
FROM
  ontime1
WHERE 
  FlightDate >= (SELECT MIN(FlightDate) FROM ontime2 WHERE Origin='JFK') AND
  FlightDate <= (SELECT MAX(FlightDate) FROM ontime2 WHERE Origin='JFK') AND
  AirlineID IN (SELECT AirlineID FROM ontime2 WHERE Origin='JFK')
LIMIT 10;
```

ontime1 -> indexed based on FlightDate
ontime2 -> indexed based on Origin, Dest

Also joining the table is not optimal as the table data is so big

How the inner query can be reused without repeating the same query again and again?

Comment: Is it mysql or clickhouse?

Comment: @simPod its clickhouse

Comment: I don't understand why there are two tables

Comment: @Strawberry two tables with different indexes

Comment: @Guru Vishnu Vardhan Reddy: That makes no sense. You can have many different indexes on one table. Are you saying that made an exact copy of the table, because you didn't know that?

Comment: Please explain again about ontime1 and ontime2. Do they contain the same data? Can I replace one with the other in your query? And just to make sure I understand your query: If there were flights from JFK from 1990 to 2020 in the table and the airlines that started from JFK were AA and Delta, you are looking for all flights operated by AA and Delta from 1990 to 2020 no matter what origin. Is this correct?

Comment: Worldwide, there are approximately 100,000 flights per day. Let's say it's been like that for 50 years, and you've tracked them all; that's 1.8 billion flights. That's a lot of data but you'll only ever be interested in a tiny partition of that data, so my sense is that you're approaching this wrong.

Comment: @GuruVishnuVardhanReddy . . . As far as I can tell, this query does nothing useful (given how many airlines fly into JFK -- or at least back in the days when airlines flew).  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, *and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and others, the usecase is different, which is specific to a project and can't be explained here, that's the reason i took sample ontime dataset and this query to explain the problem.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, This is clickhouse data store in which update operation is too costly, resulting in creating mutliple tables with different purposes

Comment: I would use one row temporary table for MIN(FlightDate)/MAX(FlightDate)/AirlineID and use it in sub-queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [WITH Clause](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/with/):

```sql
WITH (
  SELECT (MIN(FlightDate), MAX(FlightDate), groupUniqArray(AirlineID)) /* tuple with required aggregates */
  FROM ontime2
  WHERE Origin='JFK'
) AS cte
SELECT
  FlightDate,
  FlightNum,
  Origin,
  Dest,
  AirlineID
FROM
  ontime1
WHERE 
  FlightDate >= cte.1 AND
  FlightDate <= cte.2 AND
  has(cte.3, AirlineID)
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This will not use `ontime1` primary key index. Probably it's better to return only one plane row from `WITH` and use `in`.